# Spring integration setting a Adapter as Error channel

Tags: spring-integration

I wrote a simple flow for AMQP inbound messages with Json payloads, something like

```
IntegrationFlows
        .from(Amqp.inboundGateway(connectionFactory, new Queue("qin"))
                        .errorChannel(Amqp.channel("dlx", connectionFactory))
        )
        .handle(new MessageTransformingHandler(m -> {
            Object result = null;
            try {
                result = (...)
            } catch (Exception e) {
                   throw new MessageTransformationException(m, e.getMessage());
            }
            (...)
        }))
        .transform(Transformers.toJson(...))
        .handle(Amqp.outboundAdapter(new RabbitTemplate(connectionFactory))
                .routingKey("qout"))
        .get();
    }
```

This works perfectly OK, **except** when there's errors! As it is now I do get the error in DLX but in *content_type: application/x-java-serialized-object* and it is required to be *application/json*.

I could do this by having the error channel specify 2 converters

```
            .amqpMessageConverter(...)
            .messageConverter(...)
```

but the problem is that I have to implement then myself which is not easy because I have to deal with converting messages to ampqmessages, plus the business objects, plues the error object and text, and so on...

So I was thinking if I couldn't have a adapter in front of the error channel that at least took care of message->amqpmessage conversion (hopefully the payloads as well).

I also tried having a errorHandler instead of a errorChannel but the problems are the same.

Any sugestion?

Thanks in advance.

**EDITED**

Many thanks for your reply. However I'm struggling with it. After many tries and errors, I finally think I understand the solution (to use a "intermediary" channel so I can handle the message before send it to Amqp?) but I still can't get it to work. I have now

```
.errorChannel(MessageChannels.direct("amqpErrorChannel").get())
```

and the a flow listening to that channel

```
@Bean
public IntegrationFlow errorFlow() {
    return IntegrationFlows.from("amqpErrorChannel")
        .handle(new MessageTransformingHandler(m ->(...)
```

but I still have a error

> MessageDeliveryException: Dispatcher has no subscribers for channel
>   'amqpErrorChannel'.

Any pointers to what I'm doing wrong?

Cheers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can have `.transform()` or any other adapter in front of `(Amqp.channel("dlx", connectionFactory)`. Actually `.errorChannel()` is just a hook to send error to the error handling flow. So, you can use there any simple Spring Integration channel (not an AMQP one) and build any complex error handling logic.

Correct, in the end of that flow you can send a result message (after a bunch of transformation, enrichment etc.) to the AMQP `dlx`, but for this purpose the simple one-way `Amqp.outboundAdapter()` would be enough.

To be honest `Amqp.channel()` is two-way and that really would be better that you have a subscriber for it. But your case is one-way, so you should use `Amqp.outboundAdapter()` there instead.